# How come 'ou' was reduced to 'o' in the US?

Tags: orthography, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling, transatlantic-differences, o-ou

Americans write *color* and *favorite*, when others say *colour* and *favourite*. How/why did this happen?

Comment: They're lazy - they also drop the doubled-consonant in words like 'travelling'.  Or, maybe, they were ecologically sound before everyone else and tried to save paper and ink?  No, maybe not...

Comment: @Jonathan: Not to mention "jewelry", much more 'ecologically sound' than "jewellery".

Comment: But now explain *gaol* goes to *jail*.  No economy in that one.

Comment: It just struck me that the spelling "jewellery", is most likely the reason for how Indians pronounce the word, which though very different in difference parts, is always similar to "jwellery" than "jewelry"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Why do you think that "jewelry" is more 'ecologically sound' than "jewellery" when "jewellery" is the product of the work of a _jeweller_ in the same way as "stationery" was originally the product of the work of a _stationer_ and "joinery" the product of the work of a _joiner_. Admittedly "carpentry" is the work of a _carpenter_ and does not, in British dictionaries, use the full name of the trade but that has always anaomalous to me.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The pronunciation is the same, so you can't really say that some "say" this while others "say" that. It's strictly a spelling difference.

These are among the reforms introduced by Noah Webster in his dictionary, with a view towards (a) simplifying the spelling, and (b) creating a distinct American English. (The root forms of many of these words indeed lack the *u* - for example, Latin *color*, Italian *favorito* - so that may have been another motivation of his as well.) So these forms prevailed in the United States, while in the rest of the English-speaking world they kept the original spellings.

Comment: I didn't mean "say" literally. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This is why I love this site.  It answers questions I always wanted answered but didn't think to ask!

Comment: "These are among the reforms introduced by Noah Webster in his dictionary, with a view toward making Americans seem dull, stubborn and ignorant."

Comment: ...or open to change, and classical-minded. It all depends on your viewpoint, I guess; to the person with mud all over his glasses, everything seems gray and disgusting. :)

Comment: Yes, Webster explicitly wanted to be different from the British. I've heard the Americans took to driving on the right of the road for the same reason (to be different from the British), but that may be an urban legend. :-)

Comment: Before Webster did this, did everyone use the British version? Why did the average Americans follow his dictionary?

Comment: ShreevatsaR: Actually driving on the right is thought to come from the popularity of the Conestoga wagon, which, for reasons unknown, had its brakes and running board on the left. The driver sitting on the left naturally means they drive on the right to be nearer the centre of the road.

Comment: @Louis: Webster's books (in particular, his speller) became pretty much the de facto standards for schools in the United States.

Comment: Not knowing much about this Webster guy, I'm glad he did what he did. I love the reduced length. Really, what function does and extra *u* serve?

Comment: I agri. Hu nidz xtra letrs?

Comment: @Alex: As a British programmer, if a time machine is ever invented, point (b) will ensure that Mr Webster gets a visit from a temporally maligned foot in the knackers.

Answer (score 14):

Not sure how to post a comment, but this is an interesting use of Google's Ngram Viewer.  We can see that between [1840 and 1850](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=colour%2Ccolor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) color overtook colour (using their American English [dataset](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/info)).

[image: NGram results for color vs. colour]

Comment: Slightly OT but I wonder how many books in America before 1840 would have been printed in England?

Answer (score 13):

The reduction of 'our' to 'or' happens when the ending is unstressed (my accents on the stress):

> cólour, flávour, hónour, néighbour, rúmour, lábour, húmour

but not when it is stressed

> contóur, velóur, paramóur, troubadóur

This is very well explained (surprise) in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-our.2C_-or)

Comment: Do the four stressed examples have the roots in the French language though, is this significant?

Comment: Off the cuff, couleur, goût, honneur, voisin, rumeur, labeur, humour. So no, I don't see a direct correlation. I'll dig around to see if there's other answers to flavour & neighbour... Edit: Sorry, I mis-read, you meant the second set. Indeed they are all directly from French. I shall investigate too.

Comment: The only other words that I found are detour and tambour (not a word I'd use every day), so yes, it would seem that the OUR's that don't reduce are because of the French stress. There may well be -our words borrowed from other languages however.

Comment: The stressed words do have their roots in French. But so do most of the unstressed '-our'. Generally they came over longer ago, and have been more assimilated.

Comment: @smirkingman, hahaha, I always stress the `our` when saying `colour` in a "British" way.

Comment: Contour is stressed on the first syllable -- at least it has been every time I've heard it or said it. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contour -- according to your Wikipedia article it's when the vowel is *unreduced*, not stressed, that it retains its 'ou' spelling.

Comment: The pronunciation is different - In the first set it's '-or' but in the second set it's '-oor' -- That is, 'contour' does not rhyme with 'color'.  Troubadour is the one exception.

Comment: @smirkingman you've referenced a line in a Wikipedia article that has a sum total of "0" references. For all we know, you wrote it yourself; anyone else: I'd ignore this answer. And skip clicking on the Wikipedia article link.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard an alternate explanation -
Newspaper reporters would telegraph their stories to the main office for inclusion in the paper.  Saving space and reducing the cost of the transmission was important so editors issued a decree to drop 'useless letters' from spelling.  Since newspapers were the most distributed mass written product to all levels of American society the spellings they used became the standard.

I have some problems with this - for one I've had a hard time verifying it, for another - I thought telegraph operations were charged by the word - not the letter.  From some experience (now 30 years ago - who sends telegraphs now ??) there was a 10 character limit on a word - over 10 characters you got charged for 2 words.  Was this the case in the mid 1800's - who knows.

Update: It seems that instincts were correct in questioning this.  Both snopes and various fact-checking websites [confirm it's a myth](https://www.aap.com.au/factcheck/americans-didnt-shorten-their-words-to-save-a-dollar/).

I would imagine the actual answer is some compound of all of the formal attempts to simplify, common usage and general evolution.

Comment: I frankly don't believe spelling has ever been meaningfully influenced by the cost of the letters.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodyline#Origin_of_the_term

Comment: @coleopterist: Haha well found! But really that's a somewhat fanciful interpretation. UK newspapers habitually refer to *"drink-drive"* instead of *drinking and driving* - which I suppose you could say is influenced by the "cost" of column-inches. But it makes more sense to say they just want short & snappy expressions. When *bodyline bowling* became an issue, it would have been pretty obvious to all sports commentators that they were going to be referring to it *a lot*, so they were bound to come up with a short form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. I simply wanted to point out that this _has_ happened before :)

Comment: The difficulty I have with your suggestion is that the 'non u' spellings were specified by Noah Webster who died in 1843 while the first experimental electric telegraph was demonstrated by Samuel Morse in 1844. The newspaper reporters used electric telegraphs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a much less clear-cut matter than most people seem to think. The spelling *favorite* was definitely in common use in London in the late 18th century. I have before me a bound volume of music containing the following titles and descriptions:

"THE PETITION, a Favorite Hymn, The Music by Luke Proctor Esqr." (1791 - c.1802)
"Wm. Parke's MILITARY RONDO, Taken from his Favorite Oboe Concerto" (c1797 -1825)
"My Song shall be of Mercy, a Favorite Solo Anthem Composed by the late Mr. James Kent" (1798 - c.1801)
"HEAR HEAR MY PRAYER, a Favorite Anthem for Two Voices, Composed by the late Mr. James Kent" (1798 - c.1801)
"Angels ever bright and fair, A favorite Song by Mr. Handel, in Theodora" (1798 - c.1802)
"The Favorite Air of HOLY HOLY LORD... Composed by Mr. Handel" (1782 - 1798)
"A Favorite and Compleat PEAL ON EIGHT BELLS Consisting of 350 Changes Rung by the College Youths Composed by Mr. Webb Printed and Sold by A. Bland No. 23 Oxford Street " (before 1792) [The composition is false, but that's another issue!]

None of the copies is dated, but they all bear publishers' names and addresses. The dates I give are taken from "Music Publishing in the British Isles" by Humphries & Smith (Basil Blackwell, 1970).

I also have unpublished manuscripts written by my paternal grandfather (b. 1868), an educated Englishman who used the *favorite* spelling as a matter of routine.

Of more concern to me personally is the increasing tendency of British writers to hold a superstitious belief that every *-or* spelling should have *-our* instead, giving rise to such monstrosities as "Humourous" "Glamourous" "Vapourise" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [graph posted by William](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9850/how-come-ou-was-reduced-to-o-in-the-us/11293#11293), considering that the US-Mexican war [started about 1845](http://mexicanhistory.org/MexicanAmericanWarTimeline.htm) and the Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo was signed in 1848 (with occupation by US of some Mexican lands, with Mexicans included), and given that "color" and "favorito" are the Spanish spelling for color and favorite, I would say that Spanish had an influence in the current American spelling of those words.

Answer (score -5):

These are all good answers, but I think I have a more likely one.

Scholars in America, the men who influenced politics and academics in the US after the American Revolution were heavily influenced themselves by Latin and Greek sources: Thomas Jefferson and John Adams, for example, were well versed in both and at universities like Harvard and William and Mary studying classical literature was an important part of the curriculum.  Noah Webster was a Yale graduate and would have been very familiar with both the local vernacular and have had some knowledge of writers like Aristotle and Virgil and Aurelius. Webster often took into consideration the source of a word, and so often kept to Latin: honorus, colorus, and favorum became honor, color, and favor. He dropped the more complex lettering of Greek based words in favor of the way the Romans would have written it in part because it would have made it much more easy for the man who couldn't afford university to read, with only a few rare exceptions: the word for a doctor that specializes in the human skeleton is an orthopedist in American English and a doctor that might examine you when you are pregnant is a gynecologist. A wine lover is an oenophile, not an œnophile.

Meanwhile, across the Atlantic, Britain's upper class had fallen in love with French. Peppering your speech with French was a sign of education; During this time the British were heavily into international trade and French was its lingua franca. Paris had a very strong hold on the arts and culture as well to the point that people were dumping older words like "fall" for "autumn" and "napkin" for "serviette", and it was this that Johnson took into account when he wrote the dictionary, plus keeping more of the Greek glyphs that often pop up in scientific or technical words (for the doubters out there, look at Kit Marlowe: had an Oxford University education, but he never in a million years would have used the œ and æ of Greek when all he had was the then 24 letters of the English alphabet. He WAAAAAY predates Johnson and though he worked within a system where anything goes in terms of spelling, he was pretty consistent in using only the letters of the English alphabet to spell words of Greek origin, even if he knew the other way, because only a handful of people would have understood it. Johnson changed that and wrote in a time and place where more people could read, so did not bother.)

Comment: Greek had no œ or æ as letters. And what are these Greek “glyphs” you pretend were retained in scientific or medical terms?  What are you talking about with orthopedists, etc?  Plus you’re forgetting the Norman Conquest. And the law courts.  And napkin/serviette is a U/non-U thing. And you are confusing typographic digraphs with spelling.  And
*honorus*? *colorus*? *favorum*? What is that, pig latin? –100.

Comment: My face hurts, and so do both my palms.