# What is the difference between dialogue and dialog?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, variants

I am American, and I always thought the difference between *dialogue* and *dialog* was one of meaning, the way [Merriam-Webster has them listed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialog):

> 2 entries found:
>
> - [**dialogue** (noun)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialogue#dictionary-entry-1)
> - [**dialog box** (noun)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialog%20box)

According to Merriam-Webster, *dialogue* means conversation, and *dialog box* means a window on a computer screen.

This is how I use/spell them.

However, at least some people [see them as differences between British English and American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/why-does-there-exist-a-difference-in-spelling-between-british-english-and-americ).

So my questions, I guess, are:

- First of all, is my understanding, and Merriam-Webster's definition, correct?
- Is *dialog* used with any frequency by Americans to mean *conversation*?
- Is *dialog* **not** used in British English for the window on a computer screen?
- Is there any other difference I'm not aware of, or perhaps a better explanation for the two versions?

Comment: As a speaker of British English, I would use 'dialogue' in all contexts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does there exist a difference in spelling between British English and American English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/why-does-there-exist-a-difference-in-spelling-between-british-english-and-americ)

Comment: Or you could also call a dialog box a "modal"

Comment: @FumbleFingers I do not see how this is a duplicate of the question *I linked to* -- the questions are related, but neither the question nor answers are the same.  In this case, a dictionary lists the two usages as having different meaning.  In addition, you answered this question (and I upvoted your answer) -- why then ask to close it?

Comment: @NickC: I didn't know about the earlier question when I posted my answer. But a comment prompted me to *Google* "dialogue and dialog", and I noticed english.stackexchange.com near the top. On the other matter - I acknowledged that some people (incl., apparently, those good folk at M-W) think the two spellings have "different meanings". But I think this is specious, and will not become an entrenched aspect of standard usage. The thrust of my answer was that "technical" writers (and to some extent, Americans), are simply leading this particular rationalisation of spelling.

Comment: @BryanDenny - No!  Not all dialogue boxes are modal.  "Modal" means that opening the dialogue box disables other windows in the application.  That is, clicking on the application window outside of the dialogue box has no effect.  If you've got a non-modal dialogue box, then you can interact with the application window while the dialogue box is open.  Most but not all dialogue boxes are modal.

Comment: re: dialog boxes.... at least in some systems, a dialog box is a window that has a canonical set of response buttons (OK, OK/Cancel, Abort/Retry/Ignore, etc.) and non-resizable borders.

Comment: @DavidWallace No, I didn't mean *all*, hence why I said you *could.* You're absolutely right in your explanation.  Usually most (but like you said, not all) dialog boxs are modals.

Comment: I'll note that BrE tends to use *computer program*, but to spell that word *programme* in other contexts. BrE often uses American spelling in computer-related contexts.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The only real justification for seeing *dialog* as "American" is that there are many words where US spelling seems more "logical" than British - largely thanks to Webster, though so far as I know he never addressed this particular issue.

Paraphrasing grammarist.com's entry on another such word: [*all early editions of Noah Webster’s dictionary*](http://grammarist.com/spelling/catalog-catalogue/) list **catalogue**, but by the 1890s **catalog** was commonplace in AmE texts (Webster often gets credit for changes he played no direct part in).

There aren't many written instances of *dialog* prior its rapid uptake by software-oriented writers, but [here's one from 1910](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Xm4cu3bpsD8C&q=%22are%20in%20dialog%22&dq=%22are%20in%20dialog%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iWBOT-KFMNCD8gPYtKHiAg&redir_esc=y) *Transactions and proceedings of the American Philological Association*, where one might reasonably suppose the author to be perfectly literate.

I think it's just that *on average* people involved in technical writing are more inclined to ignore precedent and go for what seems to them the logical spelling. Consequently we see the short form much more often in computer contexts such as *dialog box*, leading many people to suppose there are in fact two different words involved (or at least, that the word has two different spellings dependent on context).

It seems to me usage is currently in a "transition phase", but most likely the shorter form will continue to encroach further into traditional, non-computer contexts, and will eventually be seen as standard for all contexts (but for most people, particularly Brits, this hasn't happened yet).

Comment: I think this is true for lots of -logue/log endings.  Consider: [catalogue/catalog](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catalogue%2C+catalog&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Comment: I’m American, and I can’t think of any *-logue* word that I would ever spell *-log*.  After all, it’s *epilogue* not **epilog*.  Ok, it’s *Analog Magazine*, but that’s a trademark. Similarly, the Ten Commandments are the *Decalogue*. There are real words ending in *-log*, like *antilog* and *waterlog*.  They just aren’t related to *λογος*.

Comment: @Jim: Absolutely. Although as [this NGram shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catalog%2Ccatalogue%2Cdialog%2Cdialogue&year_start=1900&year_end=1990&corpus=5&smoothing=3), *"catalog"* has been making inroads far longer than *"dialog"*. That chart is restricted to US publications, of course - us Brits are still reluctant to accept any of this "orthographic rationalisation", as Barrie says in his comment to OP.

Comment: @tchrist As an American, I always write "catalog" and "dialog". thefreedictionary.com lists "epilog" and "analog" as alternative spellings. I'm not sure when I last wrote either "epilog" or "epilogue", but I always write "analog" as do people I've worked with. The ever-popular ngram says "analog" is more common in America -- http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=analog%2Canalogue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3, but put's "epilog" as pretty much unheard of in Britain and rare in the US. I always write "Decalogue", but now that you mention it ...

Comment: @Jay,tchrist: The point is "catalog" is effectively the established American spelling now, and the direction of future change is only ever going to be towards discarding the superfluous "ue", so it will probably always [seem to] be American-led. But I'm not holding my breath expecting to see "tong" any time soon!

Comment: I am also American, and would spell many of those words with *log*.  Incliuding *dialog*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You mean "tung". :-)

Comment: I've been dealing with analog computers since the 70s, and, to my recollection it's always been "analog".

Comment: @Hot Licks: I've also been working with computers since the 70s, but I don't even know what an analog computer *is*. Even when they only had 6-bit bytes, all the kit I've worked on has been *digital*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The analog computer was that strange monstrosity at the back of the computer lab, with meters and knobs on it, and maybe an oscilloscope built in.  It was also your slide rule.

Comment: As such a box is a way for a programme to have a dialogue with the user, I would say it would depend on the language you use.  The USA would use dialog and British dialogue.  Canadians would go either way. ;)

Answer (score 22):

I was surprised to discover that Americans do indeed use the *dialogue* spelling when talking about a conversation.

Using the American English corpus:

[Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dialog%20with,%20dialogue%20with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)
[image]

I search for "dialog with" here, because that's a word sequence that would only be used in the sense of "conversation with", and won't match "dialog box".

The graph for the British English corpus is very similar in appearance.

Historical data isn't very useful for a new concept like a dialogue box.

What we see for 2000 is:

- Dialog box

  - American:  ~0.00240%
  - British :  ~0.00045%
- Dialogue box

  - American: negligible
  - British: ~0.000050%

British people *do* use *dialog*, but usually it's when they're making concessions to American readers.

For what it's worth, my British spellchecker doesn't recognise *dialog* at all.

Comment: What exactly do you think you are proving by this use of Google NGrams? Adding "with" to the terms paints a very one-sided picture. Cf. [dialog,dialogue](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dialog%2Cdialogue&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3). Sorry, but I have to down-vote this answer based on this issue alone.

Comment: @Robusto I added an explanation for that choice of phrase.

Comment: Your explanation fails to persuade. By constraining the terms the way you have you actually skew the results so that they are at least misleading, and really don't prove anything like what you contend to be true.

Comment: @Robusto What do I "contend to be true" which I claim to prove with the ngram? The ngram demonstrates that "dialogue with" is common in American English -- which surprised me because I had believed that "dialog" was the American spelling in all cases.

Comment: My point is that if you don't have a way to refine your query terms in a way that accounts for false positives on both sides, your NGram chart is meaningless.

Comment: Hmm, Slim is trying to manipulate Google ngrams to ignore "dialog box". I don't know any way to tell ngrams "dialog but not dialog followed by box", and apparently Slim doesn't either, so he choose a phrase likely to be primariliy used outside an IT context. I don't suppose he himself thinks it "prvoes" a more general case, but it is indicative of which spelling is preferred. i.e. seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Roberto: ***What false positives???*** There aren't any. Take a look at [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dialog%2Cdialog+box%2Cdialogue%2Cdialogue+box&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) and see if that doesn't convince you. Most of the increase in "dialog" is from "dialog box" and related meanings. Possibly a few more Americans are using "dialog" for the conversation meaning these days, but it's still predominantly "dialogue".

Answer (score 9):

OxfordDictionaries.com has a page on [British and American spelling](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/british-and-american-spelling?region=us), where it has this note:

> The distinctions here are not hard and fast. The spelling *analogue*
> is acceptable but not very common in American English; *catalog* has
> become the US norm, but *catalogue* is not uncommon; *dialogue* is
> still preferred over *dialog*.

Searching for *dialog* vs. *dialogue* in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) bears this out; *dialogue* appears in print almost *18 times* more frequently in US texts than *dialog*.

The Unabridged version of Merriam-Webster simply lists *dialog* and *dialogue* as being variants of each other.

I have seen both *dialog box* and *dialogue box* used in user interface specifications. I suspect that *dialog* is favored in both specifications and (especially) [code](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QDialog.html) simply because it's a couple of characters shorter.

(As you might suspect, UK texts do use *[dialogue box](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets4p6.html)* when referring to dialog boxes. Also note that ZDNet UK has a tech podcast that's called *[Dialogue Box](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/videos/dialogue-box/)*.)

Comment: Interesting insights.  As a speaker of American English, the pun in *Dialogue Box* stands out even more.

Comment: @NickC: Um, perhaps I'm just dense, but what's the pun?

Comment: @John Y The podcast, like most, is a conversation between two people (*dialogue*), *box* is generic enough to fit, and/or could imply *soap box*. And, obviously *dialog box* makes sense since it's about tech.

Answer (score 5):

As one of the people who named the Dialogue Box video podcast - and a programmer and writer for thirty years - I'd like to confirm the thinking that went into it. As far as we were concerned, 'Dialog', like 'Program', was AmE usage for 'Dialogue', like 'Programme', in BrE. The main UK usage for the AmE spellings was in IT, which had for a long time been dominated by US software - Windows, C, Unix, Pascal et al. As the US spellings were commonplace in the literature, and encoded in the grammar and syntax of programming languages and operating systems, they were used in this context to the practical exclusion of BrE alternatives and had been since some point in the 70s. So, Dialog Box would be the 'correct' use as there was no example of the phrase outside IT.

However, there were two of us in the videos and we were British - and there was going to be an element of interaction with viewers (readers? Users?), although that never transpired. So we decided to go with what we considered a mild neologism.

Answer (score 4):

To your title question, there is no semantic difference between 'dialog' and 'dialogue'; they both mean a conversation. Specifically with 'dialog box' vs 'dialogue box', the latter is very rare.

To your specific questions:

- yes, MW's definition is correct.
- yes, Americans use 'dialog' to mean 'conversation' ('dialogue' seems to be more formal)
- 'dialog box' seems to be by far the most common spelling in British English ([see a questionable Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dialog+box%2Cdialogue+box&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) )
- an explanation of the pair is a bit more involved. The '-logue' ending, coming from the Greek root for 'speech' is the source for a handful of English words: analog, catalog, dialog, epilog, monologue, prolog, travelog (plus a number of much less frequent terms). I have given these their most common *current* spelling in AmE; all used to be spelled with '-logue'. Just like other creations from Latin and Greek, difficult or unspoken spellings in English have been simplified over the years (e.g. 'anaesthesia' -> 'anesthesia'). Depending on which side of the Atlantic you're on, the simplification is sometimes used and sometimes not. In AmE, '-logue' seem to be in the middle of that process for some (dialog, catalog) and not at all for others ('monologue'). And for some modern coinages, even in BrE where '-logue' is more common, it is spelled much more commonly 'dialog box'.

Comment: Tsk - **American's use dialog**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there's variation, but sorry, yes, it is very common. For the '-logue' words, as an AmE speaker/writer, I would use 'dialog' rather than 'dialogue' though sometimes depending on formality use the other, but always 'catalog'.

Comment: @Mitch Um, no: s’omething el’se appear’s to be wrong there.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't get it. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: Maybe he/she is referring to American greengrocers.

Comment: Mitch - Sure.  (I've deleted old comment now)

Comment: @FumbleFingers ***Captain’s Logue***, stardate 2767.  The incidence of *analogs, archaeologs, the Decalog, demagogs, dialogs, epilogs, grammalogs, homologs, ideologs,
monologs, myriologs, pedagogs, philologs, polylogs, prologs, seismologs,
synagogs, telelogs, theologs,* and *travelogs* are all much increased in these 
parts. I suspect a transporter malfunction.

Answer (score 2):

The first (1898) and second (1910) editions of Merriam-Webster's *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* series list only *dialogue* as an acceptable spelling for that word. But the *Third Collegiate* (1916) has this:

> **dialogue,** *n.* Also, *Ref. Sp.*, **dialog**. ... **1.** A written composition representing two or more persons as conversing or reasoning; as, Plato's *Dialogues*. **2.** A conversation between  two or more.

The odd-looking label "*Ref. Sp.*" before the spelling *dialog* is short for *Reformed Spelling*. Spellings identified under this label reflected the efforts of the [Simplified Spelling Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Spelling_Board) (in the United States) and the [Simplified Spelling Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Spelling_Society) (in Britain) to simplify and rationalize (or perhaps I should say "rashonalize") English orthography.

Unlike its predecessors, the *Third Collegiate* included some Reformed Spelling recommendations as alternative spellings in the entries for words that the SSB and SSS (and allied organizations) wanted to change. But in the entries for words that had already two spellings, independent of the efforts of spelling simplifiers, the dictionary did not use the label *Sp. Ref.* Thus, the *Third Collegiate*'s entry for catalogue looks like this:

> **catalogue,** *n.* Also **catalog**. ...

And entries that the simplifiers didn't target—or those whose simplified forms evidently didn't gain any real-world traction—appear in the *Third Collegiate* without a variant-spelling option. Thus:

> **monologue** *n.* *1.* A dramatic part or composition for a single performer. ...

and

> **prologue** *n.* **1.** The preface or introduction to a discourse, poem, or performance; as the prologue of Chaucer's "Canterbury Tales"; ...

I did some poking around in the *Third Collegiate* and couldn't find any variant spellings other than *dialog* labeled *Ref. Sp.* (though I'm sure there must be others in that dictionary), so it appears that *dialog* is an unusual case where the variant spelling is arguably primarily attributable to the early twentieth-century spelling reform movement. Noah Webster had no hand in it: he died in 1843.

The *Ref. Sp.* label appears next to *dialog* in the Fourth Collegiate (1931), but vanishes from the *Fifth Collegiate* (1936), which offers this simpler presentation of the primary spelling and its variant:

> **dialogue,** *n.* Also **dialog**.

The *Eleventh Collegiate* (2003), the most recent dictionary in the Collegiate series, retains essentially the same opening wording in its entry for the term:

> **dialogue** *also* **dialog** *n* (13c) **1 :** a written composition in which two or more characters are represented as conversing **2 a :** a conversation between two or more persons; *also* : a similar exchange between a person and something else (as a computer) **b :** an exchange of ideas and opinions {organized a series of *dialogues* on human rights} **c :** a discussion between representatives of parties to a conflict that is aimed at resolution {a constructive *dialogue* between loggers and environmentalists} **3 :** the conversational element of literary or dramatic composition {very little dialogue in this film writes realistic *dialogue*} **4 :** a musical composition for two or more parts suggestive of a conversation

That opening wording "**dialogue** *also* **dialog**" indicates that either spelling may be used for any of the meanings that follow.

The *Eleventh Collegiate* is also the first in the series to include an entry for *dialog box*:

> **dialog box** *n* (1984) **:** a window on a computer screen for choosing options or inputting information

The wording of the entry indicates that Merriam-Webster doesn't view *dialogue box* as a legitimate variant spelling for *dialog box*.

Merriam-Webster argues that writers may use either *dialogue* or *dialog* when referring to conversation between two people in person or in a script or when referring to a "similar exchange between a person and a computer, but may use only *dialog* in the term *dialog box*, which refers more narrowly to computer screen windows. *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011)—which likewise has entries for "**dialogue** or **dialog**" and for "**dialog box**"—concurs with its rival dictionary on this point.

Nevertheless, it may be of interest to EL&U readers to know that at the computer magazine where I worked for many years, the spelling list included the following entries:

> **Dialog Information Service**
>
> **dialog box**
>
> **dialogue** (referring to speech)

We maintained this strict distinction between *dialog* (computer-related interaction) and *dialogue* (human speech) throughout the 19 years I worked at the magazine—from 1995 to 2014—and our house rule may have gone back even farther. So at least one publisher did explicitly call for different spellings (as between *dialogue* and *dialog*) depending on the meaning of the term. In contrast, we used the spelling *catalog* for any sense of that word. (As of 2001, the *Associated Press Stylebook* called for *dialogue* and *catalog*, with no exceptions listed for either term.)

Answer (score 1):

Since most of the early computer software, especially Operating Systems like Unix, Linux, Windows etc have been developed by people working in US (though not all were Americans), much of the literature referring to Computer systems and software, have spellings that are non-standard for British English. Since, most of the documentations, and even researches still dominated by American academia and industry, atleast in volume, such spellings have persisted in most parts of the world, whether formally respected or not.