# I want the spelling differences between American and British words

Tags: american-english

Well I am very interested in American English language and speaking (accent).
In India it's usually British English but I want knowledge about American English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a difference in spelling exist between British and American English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/why-does-a-difference-in-spelling-exist-between-british-and-american-english)

Comment: There are too many to list, but two of the most glaring differences are: one, the removal of U in the Latin-loanword suffix *-our* (e.g, 'favour' becomes 'favor', thusly  'favourite' becomes 'favorite', etc.); two, the change of S to Z in the verb-forming suffix -*ise* (e.g., 'specialise' becomes 'specialize'), notably not 'incise' or 'circumcise', for the suffix in those verbs is '-cise', meaning 'to cut', and notably not the verb 'size', for that is a verb formed from the noun 'size'.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

the main difference between British English and American English is that in British English spelling of the words are absorbed from French and German Language while in American English spelling of the words are based on how they sound when they are spoken. if you want to know more about it read the article: https://greatbritishmag.co.uk/uk-culture/is-british-and-american-english-the-same-language/?uid=11352 and there are various online training course to learn American English Accent.